# How to focus a specify block with {} in RSpec?

Tags: rspec

```
specify 'succeeds', focus:true do
  ...
```

Works.

How to focus this block?

```
specify { ... }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metadata must be provided as the second argument to `describe`, `context`, `it` or `specify`, so you'd need to provide at least a dummy value for the first argument. You also need to use parentheses if you want to express your block with braces.

In other words, you'd have to do something like:

```
specify('', focus: true) { ... }
```

or

```
specify(nil, focus: true) { ... }
```

See https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-14/docs/metadata/user-defined-metadata for examples of using user-defined metadata.